# Making a discrete slider using Processing

Tags: java, slider, processing

How can I make my slider discrete using Processing? Here is my code. I need to make it discrete with values from 0-10. I already put some line indicators, what I only need is to make it discrete. Can you give me an idea of how to do it?

So far, all we have made right now are continuous sliders, and the thumb travels very smoothly. How can we add steps to the same slider to make a discrete slider? Here is an example of the same slider but with 10 steps instead of returning every value in between.

```
    int x=75;
    
    void setup() {
      size(600,400);
    }
    
    void draw() {
      background(100);
      fill (200);
      rect (75, 25, 400, 50);
      stroke(0);
      
      if(mousePressed) {
      if (mouseX >75 && mouseX <= 475)
        {x=mouseX;}
        }
      fill(127,0,0);
      rect (x, 20, 9, 60); 
      fill (255);
 
      // Left Button
      fill (200);
      rect (10, 25, 50, 50);
    {
      if (mousePressed == true) {
        if (mouseX <= 50 && (mouseY >= 40 && mouseY <= 60)) {
        fill(255);
        if (x>100){
        x-=20;
      } else {
        x=75;
      }
      } else {
        fill(0);
      }
      }
      if (mousePressed == false) {
      fill (0);
      }
      triangle (50, 60, 50, 40, 15, 50);
    }
      
      // Right button
      fill (200);
      rect (490, 25, 50, 50);
      {
      if (mousePressed == true) {
        if (mouseX >= 500 && (mouseY >= 40 && mouseY <= 60)) {
        fill(255);
        if (x<470){
          x+=20;
      } 
      else {
        x=470;
      }
        } else {
        fill(0);
      }
 }
      if (mousePressed == false) {
      fill (0);
      }
      triangle (500, 60, 500, 40, 535, 50);
    }
      println(x);
      
      line (115, 60, 115, 90);
      line (155, 60, 155, 90);
      line (195, 60, 195, 90);
      line (235, 60, 235, 90);
      line (275, 60, 275, 90);
      line (315, 60, 315, 90);
      line (355, 60, 355, 90);
      line (395, 60, 395, 90);
      line (435, 60, 435, 90);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to your problem:

The easiest implementation would be drawing the rectangle to the correct position but storing the x value as you already do.

The position of your label in the slider is:

```
int length = 400; //length of the slider
int steps = 10; //steps for the slider
int start = 75; //start of the slider

int currentStep = round(((float)steps)*(x - start)/length);
//The float parse is important
//round(), ceil() or floor() will work 

int correctedPos = round(((float)length)/steps*currentStep) + start;
```

Then just draw the rect at the correct position;

```
rect(correctedPos, 20, 9, 60);
```

The second option would be storing the `currentStep` and not the `x` that you already store. Your buttons will have to increment or decrease `currentStep` instead of `x`. Then you will also have to calculate the `correctedPos` as I have already shown.

Comment: I've corrected the code, sorry for the imprecission