# Processing Exercise Slider

Tags: processing

My slider code:

```
int x=75;

void setup() {
  size(550,300);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill (100);
  rect (75, 25, 400, 50); //the slider track
  stroke(255);
  
  if(mousePressed) {
  if (mouseX >=75 && mouseX <= 475) //mousepress only works on the slider track
    {x=mouseX;}
    }

  fill(255);
  rect (x, 20, 3, 60); //the slider thumb, positioned at x}
  fill (100);

  println(x); //displays value of x
  
  
}
```

**Problem # 1:** Using processing, I need to modify my simple slider code by adding arrow buttons using the shapes, rect() and triangle(); I also need the arrows/triangle to turn white when clicked. It must look like this: [with arrow buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqn8c.png)

**Problem #2:** After doing the arrows and triangle, I need a to add a code for a discrete/stepped slider with values from 0-10.
It must look this this:[discrete slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42iZz.png)

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Have you tried searching the archives?  Here is a reference which appears similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313759/making-a-discrete-slider-using-processing